# How to use Concept Mapper Annotator and Configurable Feature Extractor Annotator? in UIMA Ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

I need to implement Concept Mapper Annotator and Configurable Feature Extractor Annotator? in UIMA Ruta. Can anyone explain in detail.

Comment: Implement or use? I assume you are referring to the components [here](https://uima.apache.org/sandbox.html#uima-addons-annotators)?

Comment: Yeah, I'm referring https://uima.apache.org/sandbox.html#uima-addons-annotators.

Comment: Can you tell something about the problems you have or where you got stuck?